# onChange event firing incorrectly after being loaded programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an APEX application where there are many drop down items. I've bound change event handlers to them using the `bind` function of jQuery.
Now when I load the content of a drop-down programmatically using `$('#ELEMENT').trigger('apexrefresh')`, the drop-down reloads but the change event handler fires automatically.

How do I prevent this from happening? I tried avoiding binding the event handler using bind and instead adding the `onChange` attribute to the element. The incorrect behaviour was still present.

Here is the skeletal code:

```
$(document).ready(function()  
{  
   $('#P7021_MSG_DEF').bind('change', function(e)  
   {  
      console.log('bound function onChange() msg_def');  
      updateStartWord();  
   }  
   );  
});  

function updateMsgDef()  
{  
   console.log('function  updateMsgDef() ');  
  
      $('#P7021_MSG_DEF').one('apexafterrefresh', function()  
      {  
         if( $x('P7021_RESTORE_CHK').value == 'Y')  
         {  
            setdefault('P7021_MSG_DEF', vJson.msg_def);  
         }  
         updateStartWord();  
      }  
      ).trigger('apexrefresh');  
}
```

In the above code, when the `updateMsgDef` is called from another function the function `updateStartWord()` gets called twice - once by `updateMsgDef()` itself and again by the `onChange` handler that was bound to `P7021_MSG_DEF` item.

If anyone could help on this?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use dynamic actions?

Comment: Yeah. Page logic is too complicated to implement using a declarative logic like DAs. Tried it but had to give up after maintaining it became a nightmare.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$('#ELEMENT').trigger('apexrefresh')` is going to trigger the change event. Short of going back to the drawing board altogether, the solution is going to be a hack whatever you do. You could poke about in (and quite possibly break) Oracle's javascript. You could write your own AJAX to populate the select list.

The easiest way might be to check in your `onChange` event which element currently has focus, eg:

```
onChange = "if($( document.activeElement).attr('id')=='YOUR_PAGE_ELEMENT') 
                { $( document.activeElement).trigger('apexrefresh'); };"
```

If the user has changed the select list, it should still have focus. There's no guarantee that will work in all browsers, but I think it should be ok in current Chrome and IE versions.

I've been in a similar situation to yours, and have come to accept that if the page logic is too complicated to implement using DAs, maintaining it is likely going to be a nightmare whatever happens. Much as I like "proper" programming, Apex is really all about the declarative controls.